# TLabel on mouse over underline?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How to underline the tlabel whenever user move the mouse over like a:hover {} in css !
For instance i'm using delphi 2010

Comment: "For instance"? Is the programming language flexible?

Comment: Do you want a hyperlink?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want a hyperlink

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a hyperlink label. The [`TLinkLabel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TLinkLabel) control may meet your needs.

Comment: Thankyou, but how to make the background of the TLinkLabel transparent or exactly as background color ( i am using a custom  TPNG background ) ?

Comment: I don't know about that. It's transparent when I've used it.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnMouseEnter, OnMouseMove and OnMouseLeave events of TLabel.

When a mouse enters or moves above label, underline its text (set Label.Font.Style to fsUnderline). When mouse leaves label, remove text underline.